# Dagger 2 injection not working

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2

The module that proides singletons of Gson, Retrofit and OkHttpClient

```
@Module
public class MyModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient() {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
        return client;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(BuildConfig.SERVER_BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

The component that allows injecting the Singletons into activity and fragments

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={MyModule.class})
public interface MyComponent {

    void inject(Activity activity);
    void inject(Fragment fragment);
    void inject(Application application);
}
```

The main application class that builds the component

```
public class MyApp extends Application{


    private MyComponent component;

    @Inject
    Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        component= DaggerMyComponent.builder()
                .myModule(new MyModule()).build();
        getComponent().inject(this); // inject retrofit here
    }

    public MyComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

This is the Fragment where I am trying to inject Retrofit.

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

    @Inject
    Retrofit retrofit;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ((MyApp)getActivity().getApplication()).getComponent().inject(this);
      ....

    }
}
```

In both MyApp and MyFragment the retrofit instance is null.

Comment: looks fine to me.

Comment: I thought the same but its not injecting Retrofit :(

Comment: @Coder Found any solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can inject Activity,Fragment and Application in Same Component.You need to create Separate component for each Activity ,Fragment and Component Like this:

**Activiy**

Use this component in all your activity:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules={MyModule.class})
public interface MyActivityComponent {
    void inject(Activity activity);
    void inject(AnotherActivity activity);
}
```

Inject in activity like this:

```
component= DaggerMyActivityComponent.builder()
                .myModule(new MyModule()).build();
        getComponent().inject(this)
```

**Fragment**

Use this component in all your fragment:

```
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules={MyModule.class})
    public interface MyFragmentComponent {

        void inject(Fragment fragment);
        void inject(AnotherFragmen fragment);
    }
```

Inject in fragment like this:

```
component= DaggerMyFragmentComponent.builder()
                .myModule(new MyModule()).build();
        getComponent().inject(this)
```

**Application**

Use this component in your Application:

```
    @Singleton
    @Component(modules={MyModule.class})
    public interface MyAppComponent {
        void inject(Application application);
    }
```

Inject in Application like this:

```
component= DaggerMyAppComponent.builder()
                .myModule(new MyModule()).build();
        getComponent().inject(this)
```

Comment: This works. So is there any way I can inject the dependencies in all the Fragments without creating Fragment specific Inject methods ?

Comment: I also came across this problem but as of now i don't have any solution for this.

Comment: Instead of `inject(Activity activity)` try `doing inject(MyActivity activity)`