# Dagger2 & Android - Decide which implementation of an interface to inject at run time

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

Hi I'm very new to Dagger, and I'm struggling to understand how to get things to work. I want to use it in a project. This project needs to use different implementations based on OS or Manufacturer or Model. But it will need to wait for Device Administrator and Runtime Permissions to be granted.

I made a quick repo with a tiny demo. The PostPermissionActivityModule is working, but the chosenWiFiImplementation is not. My main focus is how to get the WiFiImplementation set correctly in the Activity and delivered in the Processor Object. Other improvements are welcome but not really what I'm looking for.

Thanks:

https://github.com/pnogas/DaggerTest

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component(modules = {PostPermissionActivityModule.class, MyWifFiManagerInterfaceModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface PostPermissionActivityComponent {
    void inject(PostPermissionActivity postPermissionActivity);
    void inject(MyWiFiManagerInterface myWiFiManagerInterface);
}
```

This won't inject `MyWifiManagerInterface`,In order to work wifi manager you need to create another component for `MyWifiManagerInterface`

Refer this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42687686/dagger-2-injection-not-working/42687967#42687967)

And for better architecture design using dagger you can refer this [Example](https://github.com/burhanrashid52/AndroidDaggerMVPRxArchitecture)